# how to highlight the row in a table except the parent row?

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have a table, that inside the tbody has another table. Every time I hover over the body, all the body highlights. I want to remove this, and just make it work per row.

Here is an [example](http://jsfiddle.net/Dethdoll/11hmLue8/) of what I am doing

I tried using css in my element

```
pointer: none;
```

But this just hides the pointer

Comment: what exactly is the problem? I cannot see a table inside the tbody in the fiddle that you linked...

Comment: the body part, that you see that is scrollable, is a table inside the body

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to not have the "table-hover" class on the outer table.

Comment: but the the inner table won't work, or is not working